# Find and replace, where not all entries exist

Tags: excel, vba

I need to Replace entries in `Array1 = Array("11","15", "13")` with `Array2 = Array("a", "b", "ZYZ")`. My target workbook is a csv file. For some reason the below code doesn't work.

```
Array1 = Array("11", "15", "13")
Array2 = Array("a", "b", "ZYZ")

For i = 1 To 3
    With TargetWB
        .Cells.Replace What:=Array1(i), Replacement:=Array2(i), _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
    End With
Next i
```

My data is a CSV file that looks like this. Note that this file changes, so sometimes includes the **'15'** entry.

[image]

Comment: *the below code doesn't work* is not helpful.  Wrong answer?  Error message? Excel crash? Computer explodes? etc

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason the below code doesn't work.

Since you have not mentioned what is the problem, I can only guess the problem that you are facing but anyways, making these changes makes the code work for me.

**1.** Do not know how have you defined the array but change `For i = 1 To 3` to `For i = 0 To 2`

**2.** Change `TargetWB` to Sheet object if that is a workbook. Something like `TargetWB.Sheets(1)`

**Tested Code**

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Array1 As Variant
    Dim Array2 As Variant
    
    Array1 = Array("11", "15", "13")
    Array2 = Array("a", "b", "ZYZ")
    
    Dim TargetWB As Workbook
    Dim TargetWs As Worksheet
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant csv
    Set TargetWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set TargetWs = TargetWB.Sheets(1)
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 0 To 2
        TargetWs.Cells.Replace What:=Array1(i), Replacement:=Array2(i), _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
    Next i
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]